# Defining ordered pairs using only first-order logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

The usual definition of an ordered pair $\langle x,y \rangle$ is $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, but how may one define that using purely first-order logic contructs (variables, logical operations, quantifiers) and the $\in$ relation?

After reading the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair), which defines the properties:

- *$x$ is the first coordinate of $p$*: $\forall A[A \in p \rightarrow x \in A]$
- *$x$ is the second coordinate of $p$*: $\exists A[A \in p \land x \in A] \land \forall A \forall B[A \in p \land B \in p \rightarrow (A \neq B \rightarrow x \notin A \lor x \notin B)]$

I arrived at the following definition:

$$
\langle x,y \rangle = p \leftrightarrow \forall A[A \in p \rightarrow x \in A] \land \exists A[A \in p \land y \in A] \land \forall A \forall B[A \in p \land B \in p \rightarrow (A \neq B \rightarrow y \notin A \lor y \notin B)]
$$

However, this definition would also consider $\{\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,z\}\}$ or $\{\{x\},\{x,y,z\}\}$ as representing that ordered pair, and as such, it is not unique.

So, how may one define ordered pairs using only first-order logic such that only the set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ represents the ordered pair $\langle x,y \rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more or less mechanical way to do the expansion.  First, $p = \langle x, y \rangle = \{ \{ x \}, \{ x, y \} \}$ is equivalent to:
$$\forall a, a \in p \leftrightarrow (a = \{ x \} \vee a = \{ x, y \}).$$
Now, we can (by manual recursion) replace $a = \{ x \}$ with:
$$\forall b, b \in a \leftrightarrow b = x.$$
Similarly, replace $a = \{ x, y \}$ with:
$$\forall b, b \in a \leftrightarrow (b = x \vee b = y).$$
Therefore, substituting in, we get that $p = \langle x, y \rangle$ is equivalent to:
$$\forall a, a \in p \leftrightarrow [(\forall b, b \in a \leftrightarrow b = x) \vee (\forall b, b \in a \leftrightarrow (b = x \vee b = y))].$$

---

Note that a generalization of this procedure (formalized) comes up in model theory, under the name of "conversative extension by definition".  (However, in general, in expanding a formula not of the form variable = definition, we might need to introduce some more variables.  For example, if you wanted to expand $\langle x, y \rangle \in z$ instead, then you would first need to expand this to $\exists p, p = \langle x, y \rangle \wedge p \in z$, and then proceed to expand $p = \langle x, y \rangle$ as above.)

Answer (score 2):

$p= \langle x, y \rangle \iff \forall z (z \in p \iff \exists w_1 \exists w_2 ((z=w_1 \lor z=w_2) \land ((\forall t_1(t_1 \in w_1 \iff t_1=x)) \land \forall t_2(t_2 \in w_2 \iff (t_2 = x \lor t_2 = y)))).$

Translating this to English, $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the two elements of the set comprising our ordered pair, with $t_1$ as the element of $w_1$ (which we're forcing to be $x$) and $t_2$ as the elements of $w_2$ (which we're forcing to be $x$ or $y$).

Comment: The phrase “[with] $t_2$ as the elements of $w_2$...” might be unclear, so a possibly easier translation to English: $p = \langle x,y\rangle$ if and only if there exist sets $w_1,w_2$ for which a) $p=\{w_1,w_2\}$, b) $w_1$ is the singleton set  $\{x\}$ and c) $w_2$ is the set $\{x,y\}$. Note that $x$ and $y$ need not be distinct, in which case a)-c) are uniquely satisfied by $w_1=w_2=\{x\}$, and $p=\{\{x\}\}$.

Comment: I think this definition is not unique, also accepting both $\{\{x\}\}$ and $\{\{x,y\}\}$ as representing that ordered pair, as they satisfy the conditions that the sets $w_1=\{x\}$ and $w_2=\{x,y\}$ exist and every set $z$ in them satisfies $(z=w_1 \lor z=w_2)$

Comment: The biconditional in $t_2 \in w_2 \iff (t_2=x \lor t_2=y)$ forces $w_2$ to allow both $x$ and $y$ as members.

Comment: @RobertShore Indeed there's a flaw in my argument. I've tried to come up counter-example after not being able to prove the property of uniqueness for $p$, assuming extentionality. Do you think extentionality is sufficient to prove its uniqueness?

Comment: Yes.  My sentence is designed to say that $p$ has only at most two elements, $w_1$ and $w_2$, and that the only element of $w_1$ is $x$ and the only elements of $w_2$ are $x$ and $y$.  The biconditionals state that the "called" sets are in fact elements of the defined sets.

Comment: @RobertShore Indeed, and I believe that your answer is correct. However, I'm still struggling to find a proof of uniqueness for $p$. I've posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964976/proving-uniqueness-property-for-definition-of-a-set-of-sets-in-first-order-logic) to address this. Once I'm able to prove the uniqueness property, I'll be back to accept your answer.

Comment: After trying to prove the unique existence (or the main property of ordered pairs) for your definition and failing, I've decided on a different approach. I created the definition in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981949/830362), and proved the properties for it, then I my plan to prove that mine is equivalent to yours. Alas, it failed. It seems that with your definition, $\forall x[x \in Z \leftrightarrow x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \leftrightarrow x = a \lor x = b] \rightarrow Z \in p$ does not seem to hold, and so, it seems that they are not equivalent.

Comment: However, if you move the $\exists w_1 \exists w_2$ to the front of the biconditional, as in $p= \langle x, y \rangle \iff \forall z (z \in p \iff \exists w_1 \exists w_2 ((z=w_1 \lor z=w_2) \land ((\forall t_1(t_1 \in w_1 \iff t_1=x)) \land \forall t_2(t_2 \in w_2 \iff (t_2 = x \lor t_2 = y))))$, then they are equivalent, which would be enough to prove that it follows the properties.

Comment: @LuizMartins I don't see why it makes a difference but I've made the change.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $P(x) \leftarrow \exists y[Q(y)]$ is not equivalent to $\exists y[P(x) \leftarrow Q(y)]$, instead being equivalent to $\forall y[P(x) \leftarrow Q(y)]$, which would make the definitions distinct.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\newcommand\liff{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand\lif{\rightarrow}
\newcommand\lfi{\leftarrow}
\newcommand\ordp[2]{\langle #1,#2 \rangle}
\newcommand\mset[1]{\{ #1 \}}
\newcommand\isRel[1]{#1 \text{ is a relation}}
\newcommand\isFunc[1]{#1 \text{ is a function}}
\newcommand\isOneOne[1]{#1 \text{ is one-one}}
\newcommand{\fitch}[1]{\begin{array}{rlr}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand{\fcol}[1]{\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}} %FirstColumn
\newcommand{\scol}[1]{\begin{array}{l}#1\end{array}} %SecondColumn
\newcommand{\tcol}[1]{\begin{array}{l}#1\end{array}} %ThirdColumn
\newcommand{\subcol}[1]{\begin{array}{|l}#1\end{array}} %SubProofColumn
\newcommand{\startsub}{\\[-0.29em]} %adjusts line spacing slightly
\newcommand{\endsub}{\startsub} %adjusts line spacing slightly
\newcommand{\fendl}{\\[0.044em]} %adjusts line spacing slightly
$$

$$\ordp{a}{b} = p \iff \forall Z[Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]]$$

In this definition, $p$ is our ordered pair, and every set $Z$ in $p$ has to be either $\mset{a}$ or $\mset{a,b}$. This is more explicit with the equivalent set of definitions:

$$
\mset{a} = p \iff \forall x[x \in p \liff x = a] \\
\mset{a,b} = p \iff \forall x[x \in p \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
\ordp{a}{b} = p \iff \forall Z [Z \in p \liff Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b}] \\
$$

The former is more in line with the question, since it is a single definition and uses only primitive symbols. However, I found the latter nicer to work with, as it makes proofs a lot less verbose. In any case, they are equivalent, so a proof that is valid for one is valid for the other.

---

We may prove that set-theory guarantees their unique existence. The first definition will be used in this example.

The following statements trivially follow from *Paring*, *Specification* and *Extensionality*:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text{[1]}:\forall a \exists A \forall x[x \in A \liff x = a] \\
\text{[2]}:\forall a \forall b \exists A \forall x[x \in A \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
\text{[3]}:\forall p \forall q \forall a[\forall x[x \in p \liff x = a] \land \forall x[x \in q \liff x = a] \lif p = q] \\
\text{[4]}:\forall p \forall q \forall a \forall b[\forall x[x \in p \liff x = a \lor x = b] \land \forall x[x \in q \liff x = a \lor x = b] \lif p = q] \\
\end{array}
$$

We may use the first two to introduce the sets $A_{\alpha a}$ and $A_{\beta ab}$, which represent $\mset{a}$ and $\mset{a,b}$, and then introduce $p_{\alpha ab}$, which represents our ordered pair:

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{1:\fendl 2:\fendl 3:\fendl 4:\fendl 5:\fendl 6:\fendl 7:\fendl \vdots\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \exists A \forall x[x \in A \liff x = a] \\
  \exists A \forall x[x \in A \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
  \forall x[x \in A_{\alpha a} \liff x = a] \\
  \forall x[x \in A_{\beta ab} \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
  \exists A \forall x[x \in A \liff x = A_{\alpha a} \lor x = A_{\beta ab}] \\
  \forall x[x \in p_{\alpha ab} \liff x = A_{\alpha a} \lor x = A_{\beta ab}] \\
  Z \in p_{\alpha ab} \liff Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{\subcol{\subcol{\forall x[x \in Z \liff x=a \lor x=b] \land \forall x[x \in A_{\beta ab} \liff x=a \lor x=b] \lif Z = A_{\beta ab}}}} \\
 }
 & \tcol{
  [1]\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  [2]\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  1\ \exists\text{E} \fendl
  2\ \exists\text{E} \fendl
  [2]\ \forall\text{E}[a/A_{\alpha a},b/A_{\beta ab}] \fendl
  5\ \exists\text{E}[A/p_{\alpha ab}] \fendl
  6\ \forall\text{E}[x/Z] \fendl
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{aaa\ \forall\text{E}[a/A_{\alpha a},b/A_{\beta ab}]} \fendl
 }
}
$$

Then, we prove that $p_{\alpha ab}$ follows the defined properties, which means that a being with these properties exists (line $36$):

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{\vdots\fendl 8:\fendl 9:\fendl 10:\fendl 11:\fendl 12:\fendl 13:\fendl 14:\fendl 15:\fendl 16:\fendl 17:\fendl 18:\fendl 19:\fendl 20:\fendl 21:\fendl 22:\fendl 23:\fendl 24:\fendl 25:\fendl 26:\fendl 27:\fendl 28:\fendl 29:\fendl 30:\fendl 31:\fendl 32:\fendl 33:\fendl 34:\fendl 35:\fendl 36:\fendl \vdots\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \rlap{\vdots}
  \startsub\subcol{
   Z \in p_{\alpha ab} \\
   \hline
   Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab}
   \startsub\subcol{
    Z = A_{\alpha a} \\
    \hline
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \\
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
   }\endsub
   Z = A_{\alpha a} \lif \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]
   \startsub\subcol{
    Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
    \hline
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
   }\endsub
   Z = A_{\beta ab} \lif \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
   \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
  }\endsub
  Z \in p_{\alpha ab} \lif \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]
  \startsub\subcol{
   \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]
   \startsub\hline\subcol{
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \\
    \hline
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x=a] \land \forall x[x \in A_{\alpha a} \liff x=a] \lif Z = A_{\alpha a} \\
    Z = A_{\alpha a} \\
    Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
   }\endsub
   \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lif Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab}
   \startsub\subcol{
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
    \hline
    \forall x[x \in Z \liff x=a \lor x=b] \land \forall x[x \in A_{\beta ab} \liff x=a \lor x=b] \lif Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
    Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
    Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
   }\endsub
   \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \lif Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
   Z = A_{\alpha a} \lor Z = A_{\beta ab} \\
   Z \in p_{\alpha ab}
  }\endsub
  \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \lif Z \in p_{\alpha ab} \\
  Z \in p_{\alpha ab} \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
  \forall Z[Z \in p_{\alpha ab} \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\
  \exists p \forall Z[Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\
  \rlap{\vdots} \\
 }
 & \tcol{                               
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{aaa\ \forall\text{E}[a/A_{\alpha a},b/A_{\beta ab}]} \fendl
  \text{P}[Z] \fendl
  7,8\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  \text{P}[Z] \fendl
  3,10\ {=}\text{S}[A_{\alpha a}/Z] \fendl
  11\ {\lor}\text{I} \fendl
  10,12\ {\lif}\text{I}\ \fendl
  \text{P}[Z] \fendl
  4,14\ {=}\text{S}[A_{\beta ab}/Z] \fendl
  15\ {\lor}\text{I} \fendl
  14,16\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  9,13,17\ {\lor}\text{E} \fendl
  8,18\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  \text{P}[Z,a,b] \fendl
  \text{P}[Z,a,b] \fendl
  [3]\ \forall\text{E}[p/Z,q/A_{\alpha a}] \fendl
  3,21,22\ {\lif}\text{E} \fendl
  22\ {\lor}\text{I} \fendl
  20,23\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  \text{P}[Z,a,b] \fendl
  [4]\ \forall\text{E}[p/Z,q/A_{\beta ab}] \fendl
  4,26,27\ {\lif}\text{E} \fendl
  27\ {\lor}\text{I} \fendl
  25,28\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  20,25,30\ {\lor}\text{E} \fendl
  7,31\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  20,32\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  19,33\ {\liff}\text{I} \fendl
  34\ \forall\text{I}\ \fendl
  35\ \exists\text{I}\ \fendl
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{aaa\ \forall\text{E}[a/A_{\alpha a},b/A_{\beta ab}]} \fendl
 }
}$$

Then we prove that this being is unique, by showing that if any two sets $p$ and $q$ follow these properties, they are one and the same (line $45$):

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{\vdots\fendl 37:\fendl 38:\fendl 39:\fendl 40:\fendl 41:\fendl 42:\fendl 43:\fendl 44:\fendl\fendl\fendl 45:\fendl\fendl\fendl 46:\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{\subcol{\subcol{\forall x[x \in Z \liff x=a \lor x=b] \land \forall x[x \in A_{\beta ab} \liff x=a \lor x=b] \lif Z = A_{\beta ab}}}}
  \startsub\subcol{
   \forall Z[Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\
   \forall Z[Z \in q \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\
   \hline
   Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
   Z \in q \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b] \\
   Z \in p \liff Z \in q \\
   \forall Z[Z \in p \liff Z \in q] \\
   p = q \\
  } \endsub
  \forall Z[Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\\quad\ \land \forall Z[Z \in q \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\\quad \lif p = q \\
  \forall p \forall q[\forall Z[Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\\quad\ \land \forall Z[Z \in q \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\\quad \lif p = q] \\
  \exists p! \forall Z[Z \in p \liff \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a] \lor \forall x[x \in Z \liff x = a \lor x = b]] \\
 }
 & \tcol{
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{aaa\ \forall\text{E}[a/A_{\alpha a},b/A_{\beta ab}]} \\
  \text{P}[p,a,b] \fendl
  \text{P}[q,p,a,b] \fendl
  37\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  38\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  39,40\ {\liff}\text{Tr} \fendl
  41\ \forall\text{I} \fendl
  42,\text{Ext.}\ \forall\text{I} \fendl
  37,38,43\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl\fendl\fendl
  45\ \forall\text{I} \fendl\fendl\fendl
  36,45\ \exists!\text{I} \fendl
 }
}
$$

As such, there exists a unique $p$ with these properties (line $46$).

---

We may also prove that they obey the characteristeric property for ordered pairs, namely: $\forall x \forall y \forall a \forall b[\ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \liff x = a \land y = b]$. The second definition will be used in this example.

The following statements trivially follow from the definitions of $\mset{a}$ and $\mset{a,b}$, and *Extentionality*:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text{[1]}:\forall a \forall b [\mset{a} = \mset{b} \liff a=b] \\
\text{[2]}:\forall a [\mset{a,a} = \mset{a}] \\
\text{[3]}:\forall a \forall b [\mset{a,b} = \mset{a} \liff a=b] \\
\text{[4]}:\forall a \forall b \forall c [a \neq b \lif \mset{c} \neq \mset{a,b}] \\
\text{[5]}:\forall a \forall b \forall c [\mset{a,b} = \mset{a,c} \liff b = c] \\
\end{array}
$$

We start by proving the trivial implication from RHS to LHS:

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{
  1:\fendl 2:\fendl 3:\fendl 4:\fendl \vdots\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \subcol{
   x=a \land y=b \\
   \hline
   \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{x}{y} \\
   \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \\
  } \endsub
  x=a \land y=b \lif \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \\
  \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{\subcol{\mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x,y}}} \\
 }
 & \tcol{ 
  \text{P}[x,y,a,b] \fendl
  \text{T} \fendl
  1,2\ {=}\text{S} \fendl
  1,3\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  \rlap{\vdots}\hphantom{\text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}]} \fendl
 }
}
$$

For the trickier LHS to RHS, we start by assuming that $\ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b}$ and using the definition to establish a relationship between the sets (line $14$). From that relationship, we extract some useful statements about them (lines $19$ to $22$):

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{
  \vdots\fendl 5:\fendl 6:\fendl 7:\fendl 8:\fendl 9:\fendl 10:\fendl 11:\fendl 12:\fendl 13:\fendl 14:\fendl 15:\fendl 16:\fendl 17:\fendl 18:\fendl 19:\fendl 20:\fendl 21:\fendl 22:\fendl \vdots\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \subcol{
   \rlap{\vdots} \\
   \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \\
   \hline
   \ordp{a}{b} = \ordp{x}{y} \liff \forall Z [Z \in \ordp{x}{y} \liff Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b}] \\
   \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \liff \forall Z [Z \in \ordp{a}{b} \liff Z=\mset{x} \lor Z=\mset{x,y}] \\
   \forall Z [Z \in \ordp{x}{y} \liff Z=\mset{x} \lor Z=\mset{x,y}] \\
   \forall Z [Z \in \ordp{a}{b} \liff Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b}] \\
   Z \in \ordp{x}{y} \liff Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b} \\
   Z \in \ordp{a}{b} \liff Z=\mset{x} \lor Z=\mset{x,y} \\
   Z \in \ordp{a}{b} \liff Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b} \\
   Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b} \liff Z=\mset{x} \lor Z=\mset{x,y} \\
   \forall Z [Z=\mset{a} \lor Z=\mset{a,b} \liff Z=\mset{x} \lor Z=\mset{x,y}] \\
   \mset{a}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{a}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{a}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{a}=\mset{x,y} \\
   \mset{x}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{x}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{x,y} \\
   \mset{a,b}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{a,b}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{a,b}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{a,b}=\mset{x,y} \\
   \mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x,y} \\
   \mset{a}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{a}=\mset{x,y} \\
   \mset{x}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{a,b} \\
   \mset{a,b}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{a,b}=\mset{x,y} \\
   \mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \\
   \rlap{\vdots} 
  }
 }
 & \tcol{
  \rlap{\vdots}\hphantom{\text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}]} \fendl
  \text{P}[x,y,a,b] \fendl
  \text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[p/\ordp{x}{y}] \fendl
  \text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}] \fendl
  5,6\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  5,7\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  8\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  9\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  5,10\ {=}\text{S} \fendl
  11,12\ {\liff}\text{Tr} \fendl
  13\ \forall\text{I} \fendl
  14\ \forall\text{E}[Z/\mset{a}] \fendl
  14\ \forall\text{E}[Z/\mset{x}] \fendl
  14\ \forall\text{E}[Z/\mset{a,b}] \fendl
  14\ \forall\text{E}[Z/\mset{x,y}] \fendl
  15\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  16\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  17\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  18\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  \rlap{\vdots}\hphantom{\text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}]} \fendl
 }
}
$$

Now, either $a = b$ or $a \neq b$. So we may prove that in both cases it follows that $a=x$ and $b=y$. In the case that $a = b$:

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{
  \vdots\fendl 23:\fendl 24:\fendl 25:\fendl 26:\fendl 27:\fendl 28:\fendl 29:\fendl 30:\fendl 31:\fendl 32:\fendl 33:\fendl 34:\fendl 35:\fendl 36:\fendl 37:\fendl 38:\fendl 39:\fendl 40:\fendl 41:\fendl \vdots\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \subcol{
   \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{\mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x,y}} \\
   a=b \lor a \neq b
   \startsub\subcol{
    a = b \\
    \hline
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{a,b} \\
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{a,a} \\
    \mset{a,a} = \mset{a} \\
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{a} \\
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \\
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \liff x=a \\
    x=a \\
    \mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \\
    x=b \\
    \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x,x} \\ 
    \mset{x,x}=\mset{x} \\
    \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \\
    \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \\
    \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \liff x=y \\
    x=y \\
    y=b \\
   } \endsub
   a=b \lif (x=a \land y=b) \\
   \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{\mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x,y}} \\
  }
 }
 & \tcol{
  \rlap{\vdots}\hphantom{\text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}]} \fendl
  \text{T} \fendl
  \text{P}[x,y,a,b] \fendl
  20\ \text{C} \fendl
  24,25\ {=}\text{S}[b/a] \fendl
  [2]\ \forall\text{E} \fendl
  27,26\ {=}\text{S}[\mset{a,a}/\mset{a}] \fendl
  28\ {\lor}\text{E} \fendl
  [1]\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/a] \fendl
  29,30\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  22\ \text{C}\ \fendl
  24,31\ {=}\text{Tr} \fendl
  32,33\ {=}\text{S}[b/x] \fendl
  [2]\ \forall\text{E}[a/x] \fendl
  34,35\ {=}\text{S}[\mset{x,x}/\mset{x}] \fendl
  36\ {\lor}\text{E} \fendl
  [3]\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y] \fendl
  37,38\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  33,39\ {=}\text{Tr} \fendl
  24,31,40\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  \rlap{\vdots}\hphantom{\text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}]} \fendl
 }
}
$$

In the case that $a \neq b$:

$$
\small
\fitch{
 \fcol{\vdots\fendl 42:\fendl 43:\fendl 44:\fendl 45:\fendl 46:\fendl 47:\fendl 48:\fendl 49:\fendl 50:\fendl 51:\fendl 52:\fendl 53:\fendl 54:\fendl 55:\fendl 56:\fendl 57:\fendl 58:\fendl
 }
 & \scol {
  \subcol{
   \rlap{\vdots} \hphantom{\mset{x,y}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{a,b} \liff \mset{x,y}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{x,y}=\mset{x,y}}
   \startsub\subcol{
    a \neq b \\
    \hline
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \lor \mset{x}=\mset{a,b} \\
    a \neq b \lif \mset{x} \neq \mset{a,b}\\
    \mset{x} \neq \mset{a,b} \\ 
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \\
    \mset{x}=\mset{a} \liff x=a \\
    x = a \\
    \mset{a,b}=\mset{x} \lor \mset{a,b}=\mset{x,y} \\
    \mset{a,b}=\mset{x,y} \\
    \mset{a,b}=\mset{a,y} \\
    \mset{a,b}=\mset{a,y} \liff b=y\\
    b = y
   } \endsub
   a \neq b \lif (x=a \land y=b)  \\
   x=a \land y=b
  } \endsub
  \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \lif x=a \land y=b \\
  \ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \liff x=a \land y=b \\
  \forall x \forall y \forall a \forall b[\ordp{x}{y} = \ordp{a}{b} \liff x=a \land y=b] \\
 }
 & \tcol{
  \rlap{\vdots}\hphantom{\text{Def.}\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/y,p/\ordp{a}{b}]} \fendl
  \text{P}[x,y,a,b] \fendl
  20\ \text{C} \fendl
  [4]\ \forall\text{E}[c/x] \fendl
  42,44\ {\lif}\text{E} \fendl
  43,45\ {\lor}\text{E} \fendl
  [1]\ \forall\text{E}[a/x,b/a] \fendl
  46,47\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  21\ \text{C} \fendl
  45,49\ {\lor}\text{E} \fendl
  48,50\ {=}\text{S}[x/a] \fendl
  [5]\ \forall\text{E}[c/y] \fendl
  51,52\ {\liff}\text{E} \fendl
  42,53\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  23,41,54\ \text{TI} \fendl
  5,55\ {\lif}\text{I} \fendl
  4,56\ {\liff}\text{I}\ \fendl
  57\ \forall\text{I}\ \fendl
 }
}
$$

As such, the definitions obey the characteristic property for ordered pairs.